# get file extension - jquery

Tags: javascript, string

I have a `var flename = testfile.txt` in my script I want to store `testfile` in a variable and `txt` in another variable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write

```
var parts = filename.split('.');
```

`parts[0]` will contain `"testfile"`, and `parts[1]` will be `txt`.

If the string might have multiple `.`s, you can write

```
var filename = "test.file.txt";
var parts = /(.+)\.([^.]+)/.exec(filename);
```

`parts[1]` will contain `"text.file"`, and `parts[2]` will be `txt`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function splitFilename(filename) {
    var dot = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (dot === -1 || dot === 0) { // no extension
        return [filename, ''];
    }
    return [filename.substr(0, dot), filename.substr(dot + 1)];
}
```

Examples:

```
js> splitFilename('a')
a,
js> splitFilename('.htaccess')
.htaccess,
js> splitFilename('test.blah.php')
test.blah,php
js> splitFilename('test.php')
test,php
js> splitFilename('test.')
test,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var fileName = "testfile.txt".replace(/\..*$/, "");
alert(fileName);
```